# Flutter: How can I put "header image" and "ListView" in same scroll?

Tags: flutter-layout

I want to make header image and ListView in same scroll. But the code like below doesn't work:

```
SingleChildScrollView(
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
     HeaderImage(),
     ListView(...)
    ]
  )
)
```

I know ListView can't be below Column() directly. I know the way to use Expand() or Container with height or SizedBox, but these way can't make header image and ListView in same scroll. How to do these in same scroll? (HeaderImage widget is example.)(I must use ListView.)
I used to see this style in the world of web frequently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
CustomScrollView(
   slivers: <Widget>[
     SliverAppBar(
        flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
            background: Container(
              color: Colors.transparent,
              child: Image(
                image: NetworkImage('your image url here'),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            )
        ),
        expandedHeight: 300,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        actionsIconTheme: IconThemeData.fallback(),
      ),
     SliverList(
       delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
         [
           Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                for(var index = 0;index<your_data.length;index++) // Dont put comma
                your List Design here

              ]
           )
         ]
       )
     )
  ]
)
```

Comment: Yes this is what I wanted to do. I could do one of a what I wanted by your code. Thank you very much!!